# Google Drive API Files.List maxResults is not what it says it is

Tags: list, google-drive-api

I try to search Google drive with maxResult being like 10. According to docs https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list it should return up to 10 hits. In reality, however, it return the hits with the first 10 files on Drive. In other words, if I have 1 hit in the first 10 files and 1 hit in the next 10 files. A search with maxResults being 10 will only return 1 hit.

I have to pass in a large maxResult to get what I want, I wonder if this is a bug of the API?

Comment: Dup. Search s.o. for drive maxresults

Comment: what do you mean? the google results didn't answer my question. my question is that what my observed results of maxResults and it's documented functionality are different. probably this should be a bug report to them.

Comment: Your exact issue has been discussed in s.o. before. Search for it. I commented on one of them.

Comment: went through search "drive maxresults", "drive maxresults zig mandel", searching "maxresults" in all your answers. no hit. you sure you answered it on SO?

Comment: Hmm maybe I did it on the g+ forum. I see some questions that mention this though. I would consider it a bug but it appears google thinks its a feature because it has happened for years, in docslist api too. What happens is that google does some simple filtering before applying the limit, and AFTER that google does a post-filtering for more complex parts of your query filter. In that post-filter it may remove some or even all of that page's result and you have to keep looking into the the next page, in some extreme cases even many pages until you fill a real page.